# How to prevent matplotlib to be shown in popup window?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use matplotlib in my lib to display legend on a ipyleaflet map. In my CD/CI tests I run several checks on this legend (values displayed, colors etc...). My problem is when it's run on my local computer, matplotlib open a legend popup windows that stops the execution of the tests.

Is it possible to force matplotlib to remain non-interactive when I run my pytest session ?

Comment: Have you tried to change the backend to a non graphical one by calling `matplotlib.use('Agg')` before importing matplotlib.pyplot ?

Comment: I didn't but it worked as a charm when added at the start of my conftest.py file. If you want to post it as an answer, I'll validate it

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the matplotlib backend to a non graphical one by calling `matplotlib.use('Agg')` at the beginning of your scripts. This will prevent matplotlib from opening windows.